# Convert Hexadecimal IP to decimal IP in C++

Tags: c++, linux, ip, hex

How can I convert an IP in `hex` format (eg. 0101007F) to `Dotted Decimal` using C++ in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
static char* hexdecimal_to_decimalip(const char *in)
{
    char *out = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
    unsigned int p, q, r, s;

    if (sscanf(in, "%2x%2x%2x%2x", &p, &q, &r, &s) != 4)
        return out;
    sprintf(out, "%u.%u.%u.%u", p, q, r, s);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I have read that `inet_ntoa` is deprecated and does not support  `IPV6`. I need `IPV6` addresses also.

Comment: @Jackz:- Updated my answer. You can use the bit masking and bit shifts. hope that helps!

Comment: I am using `C++`. Not possible to use `printf` . :(

Comment: Thankyou.. that worked. but can I ask you that isn't `0101007F` should be ` 7f000001` (IP=127.0.0.1). How can I shift it?